# Finding a cumulative frequency array

Tags: java, arrays, frequency

This method converts a frequency array into a cumulative frequency array. 
For example if the initial array was { 1, 2, 3, 4} calling the method should give you { 1, 3, 6, 10}

This is what Ive written:

```
public void cumulate(int[] a)
{
   for (int i= 0; i < a.length; i ++){
          a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i];
    }
}
```

I'm certain its wrong, but I do need help with generating another set of codes. If anyone is able to assist me, that would be lovely!

Comment: What you have is exactly right, except your first dip into the array will be at [-1], just start i at 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 3):

Well you're going outside the array for i = 0. So start from 1:

```
public void cumulate(int[] a) {
   for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
          a[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i];
    }
}
```

Should be ok now.